# Customizing bootstrap header

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I wrote a custom bootstrap header as shown in the screen shot:
[image: img]
I want that navbar to be moved to right so that it can suit the requirements like this.
[image: img1]
  I used external CDNs for bootstrap and jquery.
 Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Registration</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/styles.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

    <body>
        <nav id="myNavbar" class="navbar navbar-default navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
            <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
            <div class="container">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarCollapse">
                        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="images/logo.png" alt="logo"></a>
                </div>
                <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarCollapse">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                        <li class="active"><a href="#" target="_blank">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" target="_blank">About</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" target="_blank">Contact</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </body>

</html>
```

**`CSS:`**

```
.navbar-fixed-top {
    min-height: 80px;
}

.navbar-fixed-top .navbar-collapse {
    max-height: 136px;
}
.navbar-collapse {
    margin-top: 1%;
}
.navbar{ 
    background-image: none;
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
    .navbar-fixed-top .navbar-collapse {
        max-height: 50px;
    }
}
#myNavbar {
    background-color:#0067ac;
    color:#16ac07;
    border-radius:0;
}
```

**Fiddler:**

https://jsfiddle.net/z4b2bwg6/9/

How can I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add the class .navbar-right to make the menu items float to the right - http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar-component-alignment

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarCollapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li class="active"><a href="#" target="_blank">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" target="_blank">About</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" target="_blank">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
```

Comment: Cool... thank you... can you tell me that how can I customize navbar according to 2nd pic?

Comment: Correct. I was able to confirm this after forking the above Fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/Xorat/ffmw77dq/

Comment: @AjayKulkarni It appears the JSFiddle container messes with rendering your code. In Clint's line 2 above, he added `navbar-right` and it works fine outside of JSFiddle. You can copy from the Fiddle I forked of your original code and test it outside of JSFiddle to see the result you want.

Comment: @AjayKulkarni I believe that's another question involving involving how that data is stored / kept, getting the right icons and parsing the data through (which based on your question there isn't enough detail to answer correctly). If you want to ask how to parse the required data through you should be asking another question. If this fix didn't move the items across to the right could you please let me know, otherwise you should accept the answer to close it off, thanks :)