# React: How can I change the color of my navbar?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to figure out how to customize my header color in bootstrap and I am unsure how to do so. Usually I use css modules in react to customize my elements [So I would import something like `import classes from './header.module.css'`] but I want to try to use bootstrap instead. How would I change the color of an element like the one below:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import { auth } from '../services/firebase';
import "./header.css"; //*****THIS IS WHERE I IMPORT header


function Header() {
  return (
    <header>
      <nav className="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light bg-light">
        <Link className="navbar-brand" to="/">PitaPal</Link>
        <button className="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-controls="navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <span className="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div className="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-end" id="navbarNavAltMarkup">
          {auth().currentUser
            ? <div className="navbar-nav">
              <Link className="nav-item nav-link" to="/home">Home</Link>
   
              <button className="btn btn-primary" onClick={() => auth().signOut()}>Logout</button>
            </div>
            : <div className="navbar-nav">
              <Link className="nav-item nav-link" to="/login">Sign In</Link>
              <Link className="nav-item nav-link" to="/signup">Sign Up</Link>
            </div>}
        </div>
      </nav>
    </header>
  );
}

export default Header;
```

My understanding is that I should pass a custom color via something like:

```
.navbar-custom {
    background-color: #ff5500;
}
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-custom">
```

**My Attempts:**

*header.js*

The react Header.js script above. I am aware I should reference the css file, but not sure how.

*header.css*

```
.navbar-custom {
    background-color: #ff5500;
}
```

Comment: There is a similar topic, maybe it will help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31668835/customizing-bootstrap-header

Comment: Where is `navbar-custom` class in your `Header.js`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this should do it.

```
import React from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import { auth } from '../services/firebase';
import './style.css';

function Header() {
  return (
    <header>
      <nav className="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-custom">
        <Link className="navbar-brand" to="/">PitaPal</Link>
        <button className="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-controls="navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <span className="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div className="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-end" id="navbarNavAltMarkup">
          {auth().currentUser
            ? <div className="navbar-nav">
              <Link className="nav-item nav-link" to="/home">Home</Link>
   
              <button className="btn btn-primary" onClick={() => auth().signOut()}>Logout</button>
            </div>
            : <div className="navbar-nav">
              <Link className="nav-item nav-link" to="/login">Sign In</Link>
              <Link className="nav-item nav-link" to="/signup">Sign Up</Link>
            </div>}
        </div>
      </nav>
    </header>
  );
}
```

Your style file `./style.css` should contain

```
.navbar-custom {
    background-color: #ff5500;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option would be to create a new class and add an "important" tag as seen in below:

```
.background-navbar {
  background-color: #9ba4b4 !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap provide for you some preconfigured class to style the background like `bg-dark` or `bg-primary`:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">

<nav class="navbar bg-dark">
  <h1>
    Navbar
  </h1>
</nav>

<nav class="navbar bg-primary">
  <h1>
    Navbar
  </h1>
</nav>
```

But you can also create custom background color classes:

```css
.bg-custom-red {
  background-color: #ff5500;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">

<nav class="navbar bg-custom-red">
  <h1>
    Navbar
  </h1>
</nav>
```

Or just overwrite the default one from Bootstrap:

```css
nav.bg-primary {
  background-color: #ff5500!important;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">

<nav class="navbar bg-primary">
  <h1>
    Navbar
  </h1>
</nav>
```